# Cant get nvm to update node

Tags: node.js

For whatever reason, npm will not work to upgrade our version of node. We are on v6.17.1 and I need to get it up to v12.4.0.
I can run: `nvm install v12.4.0` and I get:

```
'Now using node v12.4.0`
```

However... if I do: `node -v` I get:

```
`v6.17.1'
```

I then tried: `nvm use v12.5.0` and it says:

```
`Now using node v12.4.0`
```

However... `node -v` still gives:

```
`v6.17.1`
```

I can see that it placed the new version of node in:

```
`/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin`
```

When I do a `which -a node` I get:

```
`/bin/node`
`/usr/bin/node`
```

It looks like: `/bin/node` is the v6.17.1

Is there maybe another way to point to the new version of node I want?
Im new to nvm so this is my first time messing with it.

thanks!

Comment: As pointed out by the `which -a node` Operating System Command, also the `node -v` Command is reporting the Old Version. Most certainly, the `/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin` Path does not appear in your `PATH` Environment Variable. Try to remove both the `/bin/node` Path and the `/usr/bin/node` Path from the `PATH` Environment Variable and add your new `/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin` Path to it. This is not really related to the `node.js` Tag, as it is more related to your own Shell-Scripting Environment.

Comment: thanks for the info! my system will not allow me to remove /bin/node - I get a Permission denied error. Tried to chmod it to 777 and get: Operation not permitted.  I did try adding /home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin to my $PATH in bashrc and restarting the session.  I can now see it as the first thing in the path but it still defaults to that old version of node. I'll ask around and see if anyone has any thoughts on my Permission denied error.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. I am never asking people to remove anything. There is no need to _physically_ remove any kind of File from your File System. Try to search on the Internet details related to the `PATH` Environment Variable that is used by Shell-Scripting Environments. Try to understand how it is functioning. Try to see how it is set and how it is used. After you succeed in doing that, then come back here and change it in order to point it _only_ toward the Path of the New Version.

Comment: Indeed, the `/bin/` Path and the `/usr/bin/` Path should _always_ be in the `PATH` Environment Variable. Is the `/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin` Path really the First Path that appears in the `PATH` Environment Variable? If it is, then it _should_ point to the New Version of `node` now. I still feel that _physically_ removing the Old Version is a cruel thing to do. Try first to understand how on Earth it is _still_ pointing to the Old Version.

Comment: ok.. you make a really good point on not removing the old version.  I found the problem with my path! I had: /home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin/node  As you can see... I left node on there which was a mistake. once I corrected to what you had listed it worked great!! If you can plop your last comment as an answer I will accept it. thanks again!!

Comment: Cool. Five Little Characters such as `/node` are able to mess the whole thing. All right, let me flash my answer as another great victory against the world-wide Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in our chats, basically this issue has been solved the following way.

The following paths should appear from left to right in the `PATH` Environment Variable of the Shell-Scripting Environment.

`/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin/`

`/bin/`

`/usr/bin/`

Since the `/home/proxy/.nvm/v12.4.0/bin/` path is the first one that is to be found, the new version of the `node` Software Application is now accessed.